# Search and replace for CamelCase and dash/underscore at the same time

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible in Webstorm to search and replace for CamelCase and dash/underscore at the same time?

Say I want to replace all occurrences of "TodoItem" and "todo-item" and replace that with "TaskItem" and "task-item" without doing the replace one time for each?

Comment: CamelCase and underscore case it's not important for your issue. You just whant to search 2 items different in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '*Find in Path*' options and select a *regular expression check* and use this :

**(?=.*?(string1))(?=.*?(string2))**

Comment: Can I also replace (as described in the question) or only search?